# 'aapt dump badging' on ADB shell

Tags: android, adb, aapt

I'm trying to get a list of apps and their launchable activities from a command line.  I know that

```sh
aapt dump badging
```

will give me this information.  I'm just wondering if I can get this information from within the context of an ADB shell.  I realize I could pull the files to the local machine, but some of the APKs are rather large, so I'd prefer to just get that information directly from the device...

Comment: Are you talking about rooted device?

Comment: no.  this is not on a rooted device

Answer (score 7):

`adb shell dumpsys` will give you ton of information, including launchable activities. For example, the output will list activities that react to the action `android.intent.action.MAIN`:

```
  android.intent.action.MAIN:
    423fff90 com.android.bluetooth/.bpp.BluetoothBppActivity filter 42400218
    424003d0 com.android.bluetooth/.bpp.BluetoothBppSetting filter 42400608
    42400758 com.android.bluetooth/.bpp.BluetoothBppPrintPrefActivity filter 424009b8
    42400b08 com.android.bluetooth/.bpp.BluetoothBppStatusActivity filter 42400d60
    42400f10 com.android.bluetooth/.bpp.BluetoothBppAuthActivity filter 42401158
    42408bb8 com.google.android.apps.books/.app.BooksActivity filter 42408e88
    42414f50 com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarContentProviderTests filter 42415270
    42415a38 com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarDebug filter 42415c28
    42415df0 com.android.providers.calendar/.CalendarDebugActivity filter 42416048
    ...
```

Note that the output is huge; you might want to limit the output. You can see what sub-categories dumpsys knows about at the top of its output:

```
Currently running services:
  SurfaceFlinger
  accessibility
  account
  activity
  alarm
  ...
  package
  ...
```

In your case you're probably interested in only the output of `adb shell dumpsys package`.

Comment: perfect.  now I just have to figure out the grep command to grab them from that monstrosity.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an adb shell way of doing this, but you can knock somthing up in Java to read all this information.

See [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try `adb shell pm list packages`. This will give you all the packages. As far as launchable activities, try messing around with `adb shell am start`.